# How to find an attribute value for some Element in a Class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help guys, i have a class `.content` , this class have attribute called `data-time` , i want to get the value from `data-time` attribute, after that i want to show this value in `.content` class. But my code is not work better.

**My HTML Code**

```
    <div class="content first" data-time="200"> </div>
    <div class="content second" data-time="300"> </div>
    <div class="content third" data-time="400"> </div>
    <div class="content fourth" data-time="500"> </div>
```

**My jQuery Code**

```
var time = $(this).find('.content').attr('data-time');
$(this).find('.content').text(time);
```

Please anybody to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use .each to iterate

```
$(".content", this ).each(function(){

    $(this).text( $(this).attr("data-time") );

});
```

See in fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Castrolol/vAnmf/

Comment: Can i ask other question?

Comment: [click here guys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500333/how-to-do-multiple-settimeout-jquery-in-a-class) this my other question @Luan , thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding you require this

```
 $(function () {
     $('.content').each(function () {
         var time1 = $(this).attr('data-time');

         $(this).text(time1);
     });
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TApDP/1/)

Comment: i dont want to use clic function guys, i want automate detected

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..It will output your attribute text with no extra spaces at start and end of the string

```
  $(".content").each(function () {
      $(this).text($.trim($(this).attr("data-time")));
  });
```