# How to do Multiple setTimeout jQuery in a Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a class called `.content` , this content has an attribute called `.data-time`, i want to hide all element where it has `.content` class with `setTimeout()` function, anybody can help me?

**HTML code :**

```
<div class="content first" data-time="200"> </div>
<div class="content second" data-time="300"> </div>
<div class="content third" data-time="400"> </div>
<div class="content fourth" data-time="500"> </div>;
```

**jQuery Code :**

```
    $(".content", this ).each(function(){
        var time = $(this).attr("data-time");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).hide("slow");
        }, time);
    });
```

please help me to do this.

Comment: setTimeout is Javascript, not jQuery. jQuery is a library for Javascript, but setTimeout is available even if you are not using jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `setTimeout` function, `this` is the window. Try this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/uXVAs/

```
$(".content" ).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var time = $this.data("time");
        setTimeout(function() {            
            $this.hide("slow");
        }, time);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the .delay() jquery function.

```
$('.content').each(function(){
    var time = $(this).attr("data-time")
    $(this).delay(time).hide("slow")
});
```

[Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hHR4P/2/)